# Send a mail using cronjob from a Linux system

Tags: bash, cron, smtp, ubuntu-22.04

I have a school project which requires that I send a mail using cronjobs, it was intentional for learning purposes, after several research online, I got to know that I have to install an MTA on my ubuntu system, and I did that also.

I installed the postfix MTA: mailutils. During installation I selected the Internet Site option and also added my system hostname which I configured manually following the article directives. But after all of these, I wanted to test if the mail sending works

I send a mail from my Ubuntu system using mail command, like this:

`echo "testing email" | mail -s "test email" abdulhakeemyisa@gmail.com`

But the message don't get delivered to my email address.

I also installed mailx: sudo apt install bsd-mailx (I got to know this from another article I read), still I am not getting any message in my mail box. I don't know what could be the problem really.

When I did `sudo less /var/log/mail.log`, I saw some error reports that indicates that the mail was not sent

> Sep 20 15:32:28 development postfix/error[12500]: B68A283313: to=abdulhakeemyisa@gmail.com, relay=none, delay=2667, delays=2667/0.05/0/0.02, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2404:6800:4003:c00::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)

After further research, I got to know about smtp configuration being required to be able to get the mail delivered successfully. But I don't also have a clear understanding about this yet and how to do the configuration.

I send a mail from my Ubuntu system using mail command, like this:

`echo "testing email" | mail -s "test email" abdulhakeemyisa@gmail.com`

I was expecting a mail being delivered in my gmail inbox or spam, but it didn't come in.

Comment: A well presented problem, but  Stackoverflow is dedicated to helping solve `if/then/else` programming code (and tools) problems. Your question seems to be about using and configuring *nix tools. Please delete here and repost to [unix.se] . 
(Please read the text of the [tag:ubuntu-22.04] tag that you included on your question.) Good luck.

Comment: setting up an MTA is overkill. Just have the MUA connect directly to gmail to send. eg. mutt can do oauth and is scriptable

Comment: Does it work to send the mail with this command from your command line instead from a cronjob?